# how to throw error if the name has been inserted more than 2 times in sql in php?

Tags: php, mysql

how to throw error if the name has been inserted more than 5 times in sql in php??

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `transfer`(`t_id`, `agent_id`, `agent_name`, `date`, `name`, `phone`, `email`, `tname`, `tphone`, `temail`, `status`) VALUES (NULL,'$agent_id','$agent_name','$date','$name','$phone','$email','$tname','$tphone','$temail','$cmmnt','$status')");
```

Comment: yes.....it should allow insertion bt if the same name has been inserted more than 5 times than it should not insert the value...!! it should throw error....!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM transfer HAVING COUNT(name) > 5");

if (mysql_num_rows($sql) != 0) {

    // There are more than 5 - print an error.
    echo 'Error - More than 5';

}else{

    // No Error - Insert
    $insert_query = "INSERT INTO `transfer`(`t_id`, `agent_id`, `agent_name`, `date`, `name`, `phone`, `email`, `tname`, `tphone`, `temail`, `status`) VALUES (NULL,'$agent_id','$agent_name','$date','$name','$phone','$email','$tname','$tphone','$temail','$cmmnt','$status')";
    $insert_result= $mysqli -> query($insert_query);

}
```

Comment: i tried it its not working...!!
its directly showing error reagrdless of the conditions....!!!

Comment: check my updated answer it ill work for you @BhaskarGariibidi

Comment: its also throwing error....!!! its not checking the condition...!!!
whats should i do to stop it & throw error after inserting more than 5 times..!!

Comment: please show the code what u tried @BhaskarGariibidi

Comment: $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM transfer HAVING COUNT(name) > 5");

  if (mysql_num_rows($sql) != 0) {
   //show error
   } else{ 
   $sql=mysql_query("insert into transfer(t_d,name) values(NULL,'$name')");
   }

Comment: yes in ur database there are more then 5 times `given name` is inserted.so the code works properly what was the issue in that?

Comment: truncate your table and check it again @BhaskarGariibidi

Comment: i had tried truncating then also it's showing error

Comment: where shoul i post it so you check it??

Answer (score 0):

> [Please, don't use mysql_* functions in new
> code.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-function-in-php)
> They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation
> process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799) has begun on it. See
> the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)?
> Learn about [prepared
> statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead,
> and use [PDO](https://www.php.net/pdo) or
> [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/mysqli) - this
> [article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will
> help you decide which.

See the above note - I'd suggest you use the `mysqli_` function as the `mysql_` functions have been deprecated.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'db');

$query  = "SELECT * FROM transfer HAVING COUNT(name) > 5";
$result = $mysqli -> query($query);
$num    = $result -> num_rows();

if($num != 0){
    
    // There are more than 5 - print an error.
    echo 'Error - More than 5';

}else{

    // No Error - Insert
    $insert_query = "INSERT INTO `transfer`(`t_id`, `agent_id`, `agent_name`, `date`, `name`, `phone`, `email`, `tname`, `tphone`, `temail`, `status`) VALUES (NULL,'$agent_id','$agent_name','$date','$name','$phone','$email','$tname','$tphone','$temail','$cmmnt','$status')";
    $insert_result= $mysqli -> query($insert_query);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Comments re the importance of using mysqli* instead of mysql* API are quite important and should not be ignored, but since you've started with mysql* I will continue in that same route...

I believe the previous answers (using `HAVING ...`) were not answering your actual question. Try the code below.

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM transfer WHERE name = '$name'");

if (mysql_num_rows($sql) >= 5) {
    echo "Error - Too many occurrences of $name";
} else {
    $insert_query = "INSERT INTO `transfer`(`t_id`, `agent_id`, `agent_name`, `date`, `name`, `phone`, `email`, `tname`, `tphone`, `temail`, `status`) VALUES (NULL,'$agent_id','$agent_name','$date','$name','$phone','$email','$tname','$tphone','$temail','$cmmnt','$status')";
    $insert_result= $mysqli -> query($insert_query);
}
```